# asp pages and paypal button

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I have an asp.net page in 3.5 that I have a pay pal button on but when I click on the button it just refreshes the page.  I think I need to encapsulate the paypal button in something so it is not trigging the refresh but goes to pay pal.

Anyone know a solution?  Can I use an updatePanel or iframe?

Comment: Can you show the code for the "pay pal" button?

Comment: What does your `Page_Load(...)` look like ? Can you post the method that triggers on this button that you speak of?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue once, I just used the following code for my button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnPayNow" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Purchase/payNowButton.jpg" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"/>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very slick.  A good answer from someone who truly understands what's happening under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Paypal pay now buttons as generated by paypal site have their own form tags in. ASP.Net pages are generated with the whole page within a form, so you now have a form within a form which wont work. If you opt for a paypal hosted button you can have code like this within the asp.net page which will work:-

`<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
To order the item name for £99 
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="note to programmer-this value is generated by paypal"/>
<asp:ImageButton  ID="Button2" runat="server" PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but23.gif" ImageAlign="AbsBottom" />`

I know this is an old question, but I hope this helps someone else.

also, take a look here for a discussion of the issues and other possibe solutions.
http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/ecommerce/quick-and-dirty-buy-now-buttons-in-asp-net

Comment: "... but I hope this helps someone else".  Yup it helped me, Thanks!  I opted for the <a href="... solution described in the article you linked - very good article.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the [PayPal Developer Toolkit](http://developer.ebay.com/community/featured_projects/?name=paypal-toolkit) for this. They're having a lot of good code [samples](http://developer.ebay.com/community/featured_projects/default.aspx?name=Code%20Samples%20Project) and how to implement PayPal the best in your ASP.NET page.